# Use the Cauchy-Riemann equations to show that $|f(z)| = |f(c)|$ implies $f(z) = f(c)$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb C$ and $|f(z)| = |f(c)|$ for every $z\in D(c, r).$

(To be clear $D$ is an open disc on the complex plane; it has a centre *c* with radius $r.$)

Using the Cauchy-Riemann equations, how can it be shown that $f(z) = f(c)$ for every $z$ in the disc?

This is my attempt:

Let $f(z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y)$ where $x + iy = z$. (So $u$ is the real part of $f$ and $v$ is the imaginary part.)
Since $|f(z)| = |f(c)|,$ it follows that $$u^2(x, y) + v^2(x, y) = |f(c)|^2.$$
Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What are you assuming about $f$?

Comment: Maybe it suffices to show that the derivative of $f$ vanishes, so $f$ must be constant?

Comment: Apologies. $f$ is differentiable everywhere. Its domain and codomain are the complex plane.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich there is no $g$ here

Comment: @ThomasAndrews (evidently) totally misread the question, thx.

Comment: Take the derivative with respect to x. Then simplify using Cauchy-Reiman. You need to show that u’=v’=0.